# How to loop through vector of column names, mutate each column with assignment back to column and function referencing loop index

Tags: r, dplyr

If you can forgive my interest in loops, I'd like to know how to loop through a vector of variable names (must be strings in my use case) and mutate the original columns. In this toy example, I want to calculate the mean of the column `i` plus `z`.

```
df_have <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
                      y=c(2, 2, 3, 4, 4),
                      z=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

for (i in c("x", "y")) {
  df_test <-
    df_have %>%
    mutate(!!i := mean(i)+z)
}

df_want <- data.frame(x=c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), # mean 2 + z
                      y=c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7), # mean 3 + z
                      z=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Do you need a `dplyr` solution?

Comment: yeah, for this use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want to do a loop, then

```
df_test <- df_have
for (i in c("x", "y")) {
  df_test <-
    df_test %>%
    mutate(!!i := mean((!!as.name(i)))+z)
}
```

Note you need to turns those strings into symbols in order to use in the expression for mutate. An eaiser trick in this case would be

```
df_have %>% mutate_at(c("x","y"), funs(mean(.)+z))
```